# How to delete only processed files on ftp server with apache camel

Tags: java, filter, apache-camel, builder

I have the following route declared in camel:

```
from(eodRepository + "?delete=true")
    .filter(header("CamelFileName").regex(myPattern))
    .log(DEBUG, "Decrypting file ${header.CamelFileName}")
    .unmarshal(pgpDataFormat)
    .log(DEBUG, "Processing file ${header.CamelFileName}")
    .unmarshal(myBusinessDataFormat)
    .bean(myBean, "processIt")
    .log(INFO, "Processed file ${header.CamelFileName}");
```

The above consumes files matching the filter from eodRepository (an sftp folder) however delete=true on the endpoint is deleting all files in the sftp folder instead of just the ones that have been processed.

Does anyone know how I can make sure only the processed files get deleted and the remainder is left on the endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the file name filtering in the endpoint uri, and NOT the filter EIP in the route.

You can use the include option which is using reg exp:

```
"?delete=true&include=" + pattern
```

The ftp docs: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-ftp/src/main/docs/ftp-component.adoc